# CSS is not working for my proxy request

Tags: php, css

I'm trying to create a proxy request to a different domain from my own and doing some changes on the code before outputting the HTML to be displayed. And all works well except that my CSS file doesn't seem to take effect.

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['$url']))
{
    $html = file_get_contents($_GET['url']);
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($html);
    $a = array();
    foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('link') as    $href)
    {
        $a[] = $href->getAttribute('href');
    }
    echo str_replace($a[0],$url."/".$a[0], $html);
}

?>
```

The result is an HTML document but without CSS styling. But if I check the source code in my browser it shows that the link to the CSS file is okay and clicking on it takes me to that CSS file, but its not taking effect in styling the output

Comment: open the net(work) panel of your browser. are you seeing any (CSS) file downloads that failed? If so, take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: Thanks a lot, my CSS was being blocked.